# Как вывести объекты моделей связанных через foreignkey в шаблон Django?

Tags: python, django

```
# есть модели

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50);
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    # img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)


class PostImage(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='Images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# views.py

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    images = PostImage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {"posts": posts, "images": images})

# как вывести пост и фотографии для поста в шаблон
# я пробовал следующее

{% for post in posts %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ post.content }}</h2>

<!-- проблема в строке ниже --!>
    {% for i in post.images_set.all %}
        {% if i.img %}
    <img src="{{ i.img.url }}"/>
    {% endif%}
    {% endfor %}


<h1>{{ post.published }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: у тебя указано `related_name='Images'` так и обращайся в шаблоне `post.Images.all` вместо `post.images_set.all`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я, видимо сразу не углядел этого момента.

Answer (score 0):

Товарищ Andrey Maslov подсказал правильно.
Помогло.

Выкладываю код решения, вдруг кому-то пригодится.

```
# views.py
# postimage можно не брать в контекст

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {"posts": posts, })



 <!-- Код шаблона --!>
   {% for post in posts %} 
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ post.content }}</h2>
    
    <!-- Исправление --!>
    
        {% for i in post.Images.all %}
        {% if i.img %}
        <img src="{{ i.img.url }}"/>
        {% endif%}
        {% endfor %}
    <h1>{{ post.published }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
```